# Javascript Timeline Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

creating a timeline which will scroll from left to right.. running this js in console and its returning the following error

Uncaught ReferenceError: select

```
$('a.next').click(function () { selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a.next').click(function(){
                var actual_scroll = scroll_count;
                var c = selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible()').length
                if(scrolled + scroll_count >= c)
                    actual_scroll = (c - scrolled)-1

                if(parseInt(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').css('width'))*actual_scroll > selector.children('.dates-bar').width())
                    while(parseInt(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').css('width'))*actual_scroll > selector.children('.dates-bar').width() && actual_scroll > 1)
                        actual_scroll -= 1;

                var a = (-1)*actual_scroll*parseInt(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').css('width'));
                selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').animate({marginLeft: '+=' + String(a)+ 'px'}, scroll_time)
                scrolled += actual_scroll;

                current_month = new Date(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(' + String(scrolled) + ')').attr('data-date')).getMonth()

                selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.month').children('span').text(month[current_month])
            }) });
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide something like JSBin with your HTML and surrounding code as well? The error occurs not in the snippet that you've provided

Comment: Your code is somewhat difficult to understand and trace. BTW, without HTML code and associated CSS, it's not possible to analyze the root cause correctly.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/magedagone/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one error in your custom jQuery function `$.fn.jflatTimeline=`, you forgot to call IIFE (Immediately invoked Function expression) with jQuery object to it.

More about IIFE by [Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

I have updated your code as below

```
(function ($) {
   $.fn.jflatTimeline = function (options) {
     ...
   }
})(jQuery); //calling the IIFE with jQuery object
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/bsyr340y/) without any error in console.

I hope you can now go ahead with your coding.

Comment: Thank you Dreamweiver.. I still couldn't get the script to work so I just applied a click function to the left and right arrows and made the container shift left or right 70px..

Comment: hmm, so shall we close this question ?